# Flink pre shuffle aggregation is not working

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to do pre shuffle aggregation in flink. Following is the MapBundle implementation.

```
public class TaxiFareMapBundleFunction extends MapBundleFunction<Long, TaxiFare, TaxiFare, TaxiFare> {

@Override
public TaxiFare addInput(@Nullable TaxiFare value, TaxiFare input) throws Exception {
    if (value == null) {
        return input;
    }
    value.tip = value.tip + input.tip;
    return value;
}

@Override
public void finishBundle(Map<Long, TaxiFare> buffer, Collector<TaxiFare> out) throws Exception {
    for (Map.Entry<Long, TaxiFare> entry : buffer.entrySet()) {
        out.collect(entry.getValue());
    }
}

}
```

I am using "CountBundleTrigger.java" . But the pre-shuffle aggregation is not working as the "count" variable is always 0. Please let me know If I am missing something.

```
@Override
public void onElement(T element) throws Exception {
    count++;
    if (count >= maxCount) {
        callback.finishBundle();
        reset();
    }
}
```

Here is the main code.

```
    MapBundleFunction<Long, TaxiFare, TaxiFare, TaxiFare> mapBundleFunction = new TaxiFareMapBundleFunction();
    BundleTrigger<TaxiFare> bundleTrigger = new CountBundleTrigger<>(10);
    KeySelector<TaxiFare, Long> taxiFareLongKeySelector = new KeySelector<TaxiFare, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long getKey(TaxiFare value) throws Exception {
            return value.driverId;
        }
    };
    DataStream<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>> hourlyTips =
//                            fares.keyBy((TaxiFare fare) -> fare.driverId)
//                                             
.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(1))).process(new AddTips());;
            fares.transform("preshuffle", TypeInformation.of(TaxiFare.class),
                    new TaxiFareStream(mapBundleFunction, bundleTrigger, 
taxiFareLongKeySelector
            ))
                    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new 
BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor<TaxiFare>(Time.seconds(20)) {
                        @Override
                        public long extractTimestamp(TaxiFare element) {
                            return element.startTime.getEpochSecond();
                        }
                    })
                    .keyBy((TaxiFare fare) -> fare.driverId)
                    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
                    .process(new AddTips());

    DataStream<Tuple3<Long, Long, Float>> hourlyMax =
            hourlyTips.windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(1))).maxBy(2);
```

Here is the code for TaxiFareStream.java.

```
public class TaxiFareStream extends MapBundleOperator<Long, TaxiFare, TaxiFare, TaxiFare> {
    private KeySelector<TaxiFare, Long> keySelector;
    public TaxiFareStream(MapBundleFunction<Long, TaxiFare, 
        TaxiFare, TaxiFare> userFunction,
                      BundleTrigger<TaxiFare> bundleTrigger,
                      KeySelector<TaxiFare, Long> keySelector) {
        super(userFunction, bundleTrigger, keySelector);
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long getKey(TaxiFare input) throws Exception {
        return keySelector.getKey(input);
    }
}
```

Update
I have created the following class but I am seeing an error. I think it is not able to serialize the class `MapStreamBundleOperator.java`

```
public class MapStreamBundleOperator<K, V, IN, OUT> extends
                                                    AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator<K, V, IN, OUT> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6556268125924098320L;

    /** KeySelector is used to extract key for bundle map. */
    private final KeySelector<IN, K> keySelector;

    public MapStreamBundleOperator(MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT> function, BundleTrigger<IN> bundleTrigger,
                                   KeySelector<IN, K> keySelector) {
        super(function, bundleTrigger);
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    @Override
    protected K getKey(IN input) throws Exception {
        return this.keySelector.getKey(input);
    }
}
```

`

```
2021-08-27 05:06:04,814 ERROR FlinkDefaults.class                                           - Stream execution failed
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot serialize operator object class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SimpleUdfStreamOperatorFactory.
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:247)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setVertexConfig(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:497)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:318)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:297)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:297)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setChaining(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:264)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:173)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:113)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.getJobGraph(StreamGraph.java:850)
        at org.apache.flink.client.StreamGraphTranslator.translateToJobGraph(StreamGraphTranslator.java:52)
        at org.apache.flink.client.FlinkPipelineTranslationUtil.getJobGraph(FlinkPipelineTranslationUtil.java:43)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.PipelineExecutorUtils.getJobGraph(PipelineExecutorUtils.java:55)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.AbstractJobClusterExecutor.execute(AbstractJobClusterExecutor.java:62)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1810)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:128)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1697)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.FlinkDefaults$.run(FlinkDefaults.scala:46)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.FlinkWorkflow.run(FlinkWorkflow.scala:74)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.WorkflowLauncher$.executeWorkflow(WorkflowLauncher.scala:43)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.WorkflowLauncher$.delayedEndpoint$com$pinterest$xenon$flink$WorkflowLauncher$1(WorkflowLauncher.scala:25)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.WorkflowLauncher$delayedInit$body.apply(WorkflowLauncher.scala:9)
        at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.WorkflowLauncher$.main(WorkflowLauncher.scala:9)
        at com.pinterest.xenon.flink.WorkflowLauncher.main(WorkflowLauncher.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:288)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:168)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:699)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:232)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:916)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:992)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:992)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: visibility.mabs.src.main.java.com.pinterest.mabs.MabsFlinkJob
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
```

`

Comment: These bundle operations aren't really documented. If you want to understand how to work with them, you'll need to study the Flink source code and tests (where they are used to implement these features for the SQL/Table API). It would be much easier to use the SQL/Table API instead.

Comment: How do you create your operator `TaxiFareStream`. Could you post thus class?

Comment: @Felipe I have updated the main section for `TaxiFareStream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not rely on the official `MapBundleOperator` since David already said that this is not very well documented. I will answer this question based on my own `AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator`. I think that you are missing the counter `numOfElements++;` inside the `processElement()` method. And it is also better to use generic types. Use this [code](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/operator/AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator.java):

```
public abstract class AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator<K, V, IN, OUT>
        extends AbstractUdfStreamOperator<OUT, MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT>>
        implements OneInputStreamOperator<IN, OUT>, BundleTriggerCallback {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Map<K, V> bundle;
    private final BundleTrigger<IN> bundleTrigger;
    private transient TimestampedCollector<OUT> collector;
    private transient int numOfElements = 0;

    public AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator(MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT> function, BundleTrigger<IN> bundleTrigger) {
        super(function);
        chainingStrategy = ChainingStrategy.ALWAYS;
        this.bundle = new HashMap<>();
        this.bundleTrigger = checkNotNull(bundleTrigger, "bundleTrigger is null");
    }
    @Override
    public void open() throws Exception {
        super.open();
        numOfElements = 0;
        collector = new TimestampedCollector<>(output);
        bundleTrigger.registerCallback(this);
        // reset trigger
        bundleTrigger.reset();
    }
    @Override
    public void processElement(StreamRecord<IN> element) throws Exception {
        // get the key and value for the map bundle
        final IN input = element.getValue();
        final K bundleKey = getKey(input);
        final V bundleValue = this.bundle.get(bundleKey);

        // get a new value after adding this element to bundle
        final V newBundleValue = userFunction.addInput(bundleValue, input);

        // update to map bundle
        bundle.put(bundleKey, newBundleValue);
        numOfElements++;
        bundleTrigger.onElement(input);
    }
    protected abstract K getKey(final IN input) throws Exception;
    @Override
    public void finishBundle() throws Exception {
        if (!bundle.isEmpty()) {
            numOfElements = 0;
            userFunction.finishBundle(bundle, collector);
            bundle.clear();
        }
        bundleTrigger.reset();
    }
}
```

Then create the `MapStreamBundleOperator` like you already have. Use this [code](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/operator/impl/MapStreamBundleOperator.java):

```
public class MapStreamBundleOperator<K, V, IN, OUT> extends AbstractMapStreamBundleOperator<K, V, IN, OUT> {
    private final KeySelector<IN, K> keySelector;
    public MapStreamBundleOperator(MapBundleFunction<K, V, IN, OUT> function, BundleTrigger<IN> bundleTrigger,
            KeySelector<IN, K> keySelector) {
        super(function, bundleTrigger);
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }
    @Override
    protected K getKey(IN input) throws Exception {
        return this.keySelector.getKey(input);
    }
}
```

The counter inside the trigger is that makes the Bundle operator flush the events to the next phase. The `CountBundleTrigger` is like below. Use this [code](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/trigger/impl/CountBundleTrigger.java). You will need also the [BundleTriggerCallback](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/trigger/BundleTriggerCallback.java).

```
public class CountBundleTrigger<T> implements BundleTrigger<T> {
    private final long maxCount;
    private transient BundleTriggerCallback callback;
    private transient long count = 0;

    public CountBundleTrigger(long maxCount) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(maxCount > 0, "maxCount must be greater than 0");
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
    }
    @Override
    public void registerCallback(BundleTriggerCallback callback) {
        this.callback = Preconditions.checkNotNull(callback, "callback is null");
    }
    @Override
    public void onElement(T element) throws Exception {
        count++;
        if (count >= maxCount) {
            callback.finishBundle();
            reset();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void reset() { count = 0; }
    @Override
    public String explain() {
        return "CountBundleTrigger with size " + maxCount;
    }
}
```

Then you have to create one of this trigger to pass on your operator. Here I am creating a bundle of `100` `TaxiFare` events. Take [this example with another POJO](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/valencia/ValenciaDataSkewedCombinerExample.java#L112). I wrote the `MapBundleTaxiFareImpl` here [but you can create your UDF based on this one](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/udf/impl/MapBundleValenciaImpl.java).

```
private OneInputStreamOperator<Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>, Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>> getPreAggOperator() {
   MapBundleFunction<Long, TaxiFare, Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>, Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>> myMapBundleFunction = new MapBundleTaxiFareImpl();
   CountBundleTrigger<Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>> bundleTrigger = new CountBundleTrigger<Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>>(100);
   return new MapStreamBundleOperator<>(myMapBundleFunction, bundleTrigger, keyBundleSelector);
}
```

In the end you call this new operator somewhere using the `transform()`. Take [this example with another POJO](https://github.com/felipegutierrez/explore-flink/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/explore-flink/src/main/java/org/sense/flink/examples/stream/valencia/ValenciaDataSkewedCombinerExample.java#L87).

```
stream
...
.transform("my-pre-agg", 
    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Long, TaxiFare>>(){}), getPreAggOperator())
...
```

I this that it is all that you need. Try to use those class and if it is missing something it is probably on the gitrepository that I put the links. i hope you can make it work.

Comment: BTW, I prefer to use a bundle trigger based on processing time rather than on a counter. In case you want to create one based on `ProcessingTimeCallback` use this code: https://github.com/TU-Berlin-DIMA/AdCom/blob/main/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/PreAggregateProcTimeStreamAbstractOperator.java#L30

Comment: I am seeing an exception when I submit the flink job. Can you please check? I have updated the description with the stack trace.

Comment: I am using flink 1.11